# Expo Push Notifications : FCM server key empty

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I started implementing push notifications on my react native app using expo-notifications.
Today it works perfectly fine on iOS. However, using android I get the following error :

```
Exception occurred while executing exported method getDevicePushTokenAsync on module ExpoPushTokenManager. Please set your Project ID. A valid firebase project ID is required to communicate with Firebase server APIs: It identifies your project with Google.
```

I had a look at this [StackOverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65396012/exception-occurred-while-executing-exported-method-getdevicepushtokenasync-on-mo). But still couldn't get it working.

So I had a look at this [documentation](https://medium.com/geekculture/first-class-push-notifications-for-expo-apps-4bd7bbb9a01a) (It is very well explained).

At the near end, when it explains that we need to upload the Firebase project server key to Expo’s servers (which I have done using the command `expo push:android:upload --api-key <my-key>`), I realise that when going to my expo dev account (https://expo.dev/) and then click on Credentials he has his Push Notifications Credential FCM Server Key [image]

However, when I look at my expo dev account in credentials, mine is empty [image]

Did my command `expo push:android:upload --api-key <my-key>` not work ? Because I have the Android Keystore and Google Service Account Key which are filled in.